# Changing the format of calendar start and end time

Tags: 2010

**SharePoint 2010**

I'm using a standard Calendar. There are two fields from the default `Event` content type called Start Time and End Time. Once an Event has been created on the calendar, and I view the event from the default DispForm.aspx page, the format of the date/time looks like the following: [image]

I would like to change the display format of both these fields to just the hour and minute AM/PM(Would like something like this in .Net "hh:mm tt"). I've tried playing with some JavaScript with the help of jQuery and didn't really get anywhere.

```
var oldFormat = new Date($("selector").text()); // Turns the text into a Date object
```

After playing with the methods on the this Date object, I found I could use somethnig like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25275808/2658820). I thought this was a bit messy and was curious if there was an easier way.

Comment: Can you check the regional setting under site setting as I think you should be able to achieve this without JScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to edit your display form via SharePoint designer

Replace your date field (it should look like `<xsl:value-of select="@Startdate/>`) to

```
<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(@Startdate) ,1033 ,'M/dd/yyyy h:mm tt')"/>
```

or

```
<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(@Startdate) ,1033 ,1)"/>
```

For more details check

- [Custom Date Formats in SharePoint XSL](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/joshuag/2009/03/25/custom-date-formats-in-sharepoint-xsl/)
- [Fix Date and Time Formatting on Custom Display Forms](http://www.vermontspug.com/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=10)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I actually previously used your second suggestion which didn't work. Thank you!